# jQuery show href links problem

Tags: jquery-selectors, href

New to this, so sorry if it's really silly.  My problem is as follows.  We have been given a list of anchors, some are html and some are pdf.  These are  grouped into a div #anchors which is to be hidden on document ready.  Then two buttons with a choice to show either html links only or pdf links only and the href$ selector must be used.  I can't get anything to show.  Code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Anchors hidden");
    $('#anchors').hide();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#htmlLinks').click(function(event){
    alert("html pressed");
    $("a[href$=html]").show();
  });
});
```

The alert shows, but none of the links are listed.  I've tried loads of things.  What am I doing wrong?  I've tried `$('#anchor a[href$=".html"]').show();` and various other things with different combinations of quotation marks, I've tried creating a new div and outputting to that, but I'm getting nowhere.  I can get the whole div to display, but not a selection of it.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Can you show an excerpt of your html, ideally showing the container (`#anchors`) and a couple of links of each type? Just so's we can be sure of what you're working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hiding the whole div here:

```
$('#anchors').hide();
```

Instead, hide the anchors inside...the ones you want to show, like this:

```
$('#anchors a').hide();
```

If you [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) a child that still in a hidden parent you'll get no effect, which is what you're seeing.  Instead do a [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) on the hidden element directly, and leave the parent visible.

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to as well, but (and I think I got this right) the [demo I was putting together](http://jsbin.com/aheno3/2/) didn't seem to bear that out. Or have I just made a huge rookie mistake in there?

Comment: Nick, you are a superstar!  I've been banging my head against this for hours.  I could bloomin' well kiss you. :D

Comment: @David - Your selectors are off for your click handlers, they're classes where you have IDs, here's the updated version: http://jsbin.com/aheno3/3/edit

Comment: huge *and* embarrassing mistake...sigh. Thanks, I was staring at that for five minutes thinking 'whuh?' =)

Comment: @David - I like that people think others don't do the same thing at least 5 times a day....we all do, I'm up to twice today so far :)